# form label does not get width in css

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML form [here][1]. I am setting label's display to `inline` and `width` to `200px` but it does not get the width. How can I give width so that it takes it?

Here is my [form](http://jsfiddle.net/eZH5C/)

```
<form>
<div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <label>Organization</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
</form>
```

And the CSS:

```
label {
    display: inline;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: you want all input fields inline?

Comment: Use inline-block instead. http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/eZH5C/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot give a `width` to an `inline` element. You have to set its `display` to `inline-block` if you want it to be inline **and** have a width.

Changing your CSS to

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

makes it work.

**live demo**: http://dabblet.com/gist/3149758

Answer (score 2):

The width property does not apply to inline, non-replaced elements.

Don't set the display to inline. You might like inline-block instead.

Answer (score 1):

The inline property won't read width. You need to use `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` for the width to be read.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.

```
label {

    width: 200px ;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
​input[type="text"]{
    float:left;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyways **label** is already a **inline** elements so there is no use of setting style to `display:inline;`.

if you want to add width first make the element a block element. you can do this by using `display:inline-block` or use `display:block; & float:left;`

**Fiddle demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/eZH5C/1/